# How to take a photograph as it is?

Tags: digital

How do I take a photograph of anything in its original without any processing done on the image/photograph?

Most of the digital cameras apply colour/light corrections after the image is captured.

Analog/film is almost gone and outdated. If analog cameras can capture an image in its original then answer about that, too.

Comment: This is more like a pholosophical question. You can not take the original without any processing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Nearly all cameras allow you to change those settings, to *Neutral*, or *'0,0,0'* or whatever they call it. Note that the results will look bland to you, because we are all *used to* see photos sharpened and saturation/contrast-enhanced. But they are pretty near to the original.
2. if you use the RAW file that better cameras produce, you will always get it unprocessed. Same comment applies here, though.

If you mean *really really original* - there is no way to exactly have it *original* - every digital chip has its behaviors, and although the manufacturers try to make it as good as possible, there are deviations. The same is true for analog film - the three color layer differ lightly from film to film, and minuscule changes in the development process (solution concentration, soaking duration, etc.) result in slightly different results. A high-end digital camera is probably the nearest you can get.

Also, every eye sees different, and every brain processes different...